# Should a Go app panic if it doesn't find external dependencies/services

Tags: go

How should a Golang app handle missing external dependencies ? 
When a app starts and it doesn't find the database it is supposed to persist the data on, knowing the app is useless in that state, should I panic the app ?

I can otherwise log infinitely something, print to stderr, or use another method to notify, but I'm not sure when to choose each method.

Comment: If the absence of the dependency makes your application useless and implies an unrecoverable error, you may well panic the app. Panic ends the applciation, so do it when you need to fix something and re-launch the app.

Comment: That depends on your needs. In some cases, a panic is ideal. In other cases, a panic is absolutely the worst answer, and a better answer is a retry-loop, a cache fallback, a "service unavailable" message, or any countless number of other fault-tolerance strategies.

Comment: This is 100% situational and no one can answer this question for you. I would generally say though that a literal `panic` is probably unnecessary, as in the case of something like this you probably don't need the stack trace. Just log and exit.

Comment: Adrian, exiting the app is a better solution for you rather than looping around a log or doing a "pool retry" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application that has no access to the **external** network service **should not panic**. This should be expected as networks tend to fail. I would wrap the error and pass it further.

Consider the following scenario. You have multiple application servers connected to two database servers. You are upgrading the database servers one at a time. When one is turned off half of your application servers panicked and crashed. You upgrade the second database server and every application server is gone now. Instead, when the database is not available just report an error for instance by sending HTTP status 500. If you have a load balancer it will pass the request to the working applications servers. When the database server is back, the application servers reconnect and continue to work.

Another scenario, you are running an interactive application that processes a database to create a report. The connection is not available. The application panicked and crashed. From the user perspective, it looks like a bug. I would expect a message that connection cannot be established.

In the standard library it is accepted to panic when an **internal** resource is not available. See [template.Must](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must). This means something is wrong with the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from the Go standard library.

> [Package crypto](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/)
>
> ```
> import "crypto"
> ```
>
> [func (Hash) New](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#Hash.New)
>
> ```
> func (h Hash) New() hash.Hash
> ```
>
> New returns a new hash.Hash calculating the given hash function. New
>   panics if the hash function is not linked into the binary.